# datatool: get rid of a specific character

Tags: datatool

How can I get rid of a character while loading a table from a file with datatool? In my case, I like to get rid of every double quote that appears within the data.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{members.csv}
"Rolle/Status","Vorname","Nachname"
"Mitglied","FirstName1","LastName1"
"Mitglied","FirstName2","LastName2"
"Mitglied","FirstName3","LastName3"
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLsetdelimiter{,}
\DTLloaddb{members}{members.csv}

\begin{document}

\multido{\nx = 1+1}{\DTLrowcount{members}}{
  \DTLgetvalue{\studentlastname}{members}{\nx}{3}
  \DTLgetvalue{\studentfirstname}{members}{\nx}{2}
  \studentlastname
  \studentfirstname
}

\end{document}
```

By the way, when I add an extra line between \DTLgetvalue and \studentlastname, I'll get multiple errors. What is the reason?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I just added a MWE. I'll like to get rid of the ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `\multido` for cycling through the rows of a database, since `datatool` provides `\DTLforeach`; see section 5.4 in the manual of `datatool`.

If you're sure that *all* entries are between quotes, this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{members.csv}
"Rolle/Status","Vorname","Nachname"
"Mitglied","FirstName1","LastName1"
"Mitglied","FirstName2","LastName2"
"Mitglied","FirstName3","LastName3"
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\stripquotes[1]{\expandafter\dostripquotes#1}
\def\dostripquotes"#1"{#1} % \def is necessary here

\DTLsetdelimiter{,}
\DTLloaddb{members}{members.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{members}{%
  \studentfirstname="Vorname",
  \studentlastname="Nachname"}
  {\stripquotes{\studentlastname}, \stripquotes{\studentfirstname}\par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem: I need the multido loop since I want to do something else for each row. To be precise: I want to make an exam where on each the student name and an ID is written. I am running through a multido loop to print an exam for every row=every student.

Comment: @DaPhil There's no need of `\multido`.